# Tricky System of Equations

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

I am at the last part of an extended proof I am working on and it's come down to a tricky system.

Given the following:
$af+bg=-2$
$ah+bi=0$
$df+eg=2$
$dh+ei=3$

I want to show that $-2dh+3af-2ah=-6$.
Or even that $-2dh+3af-2ah$ is fixed for any choice of $a,b,d,e,f,g,h,i$.

I've tested numbers and I know that this is the case but I haven't been able to show this formally. Much obliged!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system is equivalent to the matrix equation:

$$
(I)\qquad
\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\ d&e\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}f&h\\ g&i\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}-2&0\\ 2&3\end{bmatrix}
$$
And you are interested in $-2dh+3af-2ah$ which can be written as
$$
(II)\qquad
\begin{bmatrix}a&b&d&e\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}3&0&-2&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&-2&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}f\\g\\h\\i \end{bmatrix}
$$

Now vectorizing $(I)$ yields

$$
(I')\qquad
\begin{bmatrix}a&b&0&0\\d&e&0&0\\0&0&a&b\\0&0&d&e\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}f\\g\\h\\i \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}-2\\2\\0\\3 \end{bmatrix}
$$

The idea is now to choose $\begin{bmatrix}x&y&z&w\end{bmatrix}$ such that

$$
\begin{bmatrix}x&y&z&w\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}a&b&0&0\\d&e&0&0\\0&0&a&b\\0&0&d&e\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}a&b&d&e\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}3&0&-2&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&-2&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}
$$

Or equivalently

$$
\begin{bmatrix}a&d&0&0\\b&e&0&0\\0&0&a&d\\0&0&b&e\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\w\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}3a\\0\\-2a-2d\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$

Which is uniquely solveable if $\det\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\ d&e\end{bmatrix} \neq 0$, after which you only need to multiply $(I')$ by $\begin{bmatrix}x&y&z&w\end{bmatrix}$

EDIT: If my calculation is correct,

$$
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\w\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}3+3\frac{bd}{D}\\-3\frac{ab}{D}\\-2\frac{a+d}{a}(1+\frac{bd}{D})\\\frac{2(a+d)b}{D}\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
D = \det\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\ d&e\end{bmatrix}
$$

And then

$$
\begin{bmatrix}x&y&z&w\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}-2\\2\\0\\3 \end{bmatrix}
= -6-6\frac{bd}{D} - 6\frac{ab}{D} + 6\frac{(a+d)b}{D} = -6
$$

Q.E.D.

Comment: Brilliant, and I can verify that determinant is nonzero from a previous part of my proof. Thanks dude